# Setting up NFS client shows "local domain name not set" error

Tags: 10.04, configuration, nfs

I'm having trouble configuring the machine to use nfs. I have installed autofs, and tried to configure it. But the problem is that the configuration I use on OpenSuSe machines isn't working.

First problem was a missing line in `nsswitch.conf`:

I added the line: `automount:      nis files`

But now I get this:

`automount[2285]: lookup_init:136: lookup(yp): map auto.master: Local domain name not set`

This is a local network setup, therefore I'm completely confused by this error. Why should nfs client require a domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by executing `hostname computer_name`. I really have no idea why this wasn't set up during installation.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right in the logmessage, the domainname of the system is not set:
just try:

```
domainname localdomain
```

nfs4 needs the domainname ... Probably you are mounting an nfs4 share. Check your NAS or whatever